# Separate (ir)regular expression

Tags: php, python, regex

I have a string:

```
A12B34C10G34LongerLongerEven LongerA57
```

Is there any way to separate the above using regular expressions to the form of:

```
A12,B34,C10,G34,Longer,Longer,Even Longer,A57
```

So, separated by commas. I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Python or PHP, which do you want?

Answer (score 3):

This gives what you need:

```
<?php
$str = "A12B34C10G34LongerLongerEven LongerA57";

echo preg_replace('/([^\s])([A-Z])/', '\1,\2', $str), "\n";

// OUTPUT: A12,B34,C10,G34,Longer,Longer,Even Longer,A57
```

Comment: `\S` can be used instead of `[^\s]`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace ('/\B([A-Z])/',',$1',$string);
```

Inserts a comma before any capital letter that is not on a word boundary.

*My assumption is that the input data can consist of capital letters followed by numbers and capitalized words that may or may not be separated by spaces.*

Comment: This would be my favorite answer, except the slashes in the second argument are wrong.  PHP requires you to add delimiters to the regex, but not to the replacement.  And while it's not incorrect, you don't have to wrap the word boundary in a lookaround to invert its meaning; just use the negated form: `\B([A-Z])`.

Comment: The result with Alan Moore's pattern is ``A12"B34#C10,G3-Longer,March`` for string ``'A12"B34#C10G3-LongerMarch'``

Comment: @eyquem, I tested it and it did not put a comma at the head (both the original pattern and the revised one).

Comment: @dan1111 Concerning pattern ``'(?<!\b)([A-Z])'``, are you sure ? I assert that in Python, it produces a comma at the head of the result. I must conclude that it's a difference between Python's and PHP's regexes and I'm surprised of this. - However, as I said, capital letters preceded by a non-underscore, non-digit, non-letter chararacter (the meaning of ``\B([A-Z])``) remain not detected as fitting boundary after revision

Comment: @eyquem, I offered this as a PHP solution and didn't test in Python.  If Python does not allow a word boundary to occur at the beginning of the string, that seems like a flaw of Python to me. This regex works fine for data of the form shown in the question (capital letter followed by numbers, capitalized words possibly separated by spaces).  I am aware that it would fail when used on data that is very different from what was shown in the question.

Comment: @dan1111 That's not a flaw of Python, that's a flaw of me. I found the problem is my writing. I tested with pattern ``'(?<!\b)([A-Z])'`` whereas it must be ``'(?<!\\b)([A-Z])'``. With this last one, the result is without heading comma. Sorry

Comment: @dan1111 For data, I suppose you did the same assumption as DJV: _"Assuming you want to add a ',' in front of each upper case character that is not preceded by a **space**,..."_ since OP said nothing about criteria. Thinking to the possibility that the preceding character may be a ``\W`` isn't pushing the assumption very far, a blank being only one of the characters of the ``\w`` category logically implied in the meaning of ``\b`` and ``\B``. You're not technically wrong with your answer. I mean it's fair to warn someone about possible evident inconveniences of a solution based on assumption

Comment: @dan1111 By the way, as far as I know, ``\\b`` is the only escaped sequence that requires to be written ``\\b`` and not only ``\b`` in a regex's pattern because it also means **bell**. The others can be written ``\n``, ``\t`` ... without any problem. How is it in PHP ? What's the character to mean a bell sound, please ?

Comment: @eyquem, in PHP, single-quoted strings do not escape at all (except for `\'`).  Thus any escape sequences are passed directly to the regex engine.  I will update the answer to explain my assumptions.  You do have a good point about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

ss = ' \tA12B34C10#G34LongerVery LongerEven LongerA57 \n'

print '%r\n%r\n\n%r' %\
      (
       #good 1
       re.sub('(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])', ',', ss),

       #good 2
       ','.join(
           re.findall('(\s*[A-Z].+?\s*)(?=(?<=\S)[A-Z]|\s*\Z)',ss)
           ),


       #bad (written at first)
       ','.join(
           re.findall('(?<!\s)([A-Z].+?)(?<!\s)(?![^A-Z])',ss)
           )
       )
```

result

```
' \tA12,B34,C10#,G34,Longer,Very Longer,Even Longer,A57 \n'
' \tA12,B34,C10#,G34,Longer,Very Longer,Even Longer,A57 \n'

'B34,C10#,G34,Longer,Very Longer,Even Longer'
```

.

The first solution is as close to the idea (**inserting** a comma) as possible.
`(?<=\S)` is mandatory in this solution because each comma must be inserted **between** characters   (correction from DJV)
`(?<!\s)` would match the beginning of string and a comma would be prepended at the very first position.

.

In a first writing, I had written second solution as

```
# bad
','.join(re.findall( '(?<!\s)([A-Z].+?)(?<!\s)(?![^A-Z])', ss) )
```

or

```
# bad    
``','.join(re.findall( '(?<!\s)([A-Z].+?)(?<!\s)(?=[A-Z]|\Z)', ss) )``
```

where
`(?![^A-Z])` or `(?=[A-Z]|\Z)` were to take account of the end of the string as a possible end of matching portion.
Then
I realized that if whitespaces are at the beginning or the end of the string, there are problems. The above code shows which ones.
To prevent these problems, the solution is the good solution number 2. But it's a complicated one harder to get, so the good solution number 1 is  evidently my prefered one.

Comment: Btw, the `re.sub`, should use `(?<=[^ ])` or `(<=\S)`, cause `(?<!\s)` prepends a comma at the very beginning (it matches the beginning of the string I think)

Comment: Thank you very much, DJV. I wonder how I could post a code that didn't work, I don't understand how I could do that. I went in your user's pages and then I upvoted 5 of your answers.

Comment: @DJV Thank you very much, DJV. I wonder how I could post a code that didn't work, I don't understand how I could do that. I went in your user's pages and then I upvoted 5 of your answers.

Comment: +1 on your lookahead which I didn't manage to think of in my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$in = 'A12B34C10G34LongerLongerEven LongerA57';
$output = trim(preg_replace('/([^\s])([A-Z])/', "$1,$2", $in),",");
echo $output;
```

output : `A12,B34,C10,G34,Longer,Longer,Even Longer,A57`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add a `','` in front of each upper case character that is not preceded by a space, here is simple Python `regex` + `sub` way of doing it.

```
string = 'A12B34C10G34LongerLongerEven LongerA57'
re.sub(r'(?<=[^ ])([A-Z])', lambda x: ',' + x.group(0), string)
```

outputs:

```
'A12,B34,C10,G34,Longer,Longer,Even Longer,A57'
```

The `regex` makes a lookbehind to check for a non-space and the match is an upper character. Then this upper char is prepended a `','`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this assuming you won't get a comma anywhere in `$in`

```
explode(",", preg_replace('/([^\s])([A-Z]+)/', "$1,$2", $in);
```

I don't really know python, but the base regex is the same.